# get an element position using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to find an element position using JQuery. Not the X and Y position using .position .

For exemple

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

And the js

```
//return the li pos
$('li').click(function(){...})
```

for exemple if I click the third li the function return the li pos witch is 2

I try something but it doesn't works

```
$('li').click(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $('li').length; i++){
        if($('li:eq('+i+')') == $(this)){
            alert(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert('fail');
    return false;
})
```

And I always get fail

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [**index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the position. It gives you `zero-based index` so you will get `0` for first element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/R76Zc/)**

```
$('li').click(function(){    
    alert($(this).index())
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind, index is 0 based. If you want 1 based then of course you'll need to add one to your index result

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `.index()` to find the position of li

```
$('li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).index());
})​
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/2mR5U/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `prev()` method to return the previous element.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var previous = $(this).prev();

    console.log(previous.index());
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `.prev()`?

Answer (score 0):

try it ( http://jsfiddle.net/DfXwq/ ):

```
$('li').click(function(e){
    var target = e.target,
        parent = target.parentNode
        number = $(parent).children().index(target );

    console.log(number);
});​
```